Powershell send one email after checking all paths for files
I have a script which checks if there are new files in several folders and then it sends an e-mail with log file if there are new files.
$source = Get-Content "C:\AAA\source.txt"
$logDate = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
$logtime = get-date -format HH:mm
$log = "C:\AAA\$logdate.log"

$mailkomu = "EEE@EEE.com"
$mailod = "GGG@GGG.com"
$subject = "New files in DDD"
$zprava = "Message"

ForEach($path in $source){
    Test-path $path
    Write-Output "$logtime - $path - ok" | Out-File $log -Append 
    If ((Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "no files" | Out-File $log -Append
    }
    Else { 
        Write-Output "new files" | Out-File $log -Append
        $data = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Select-Object DirectoryName, Name
        $data | Out-File $log -Append
        Send-MailMessage -From $mailod -To $mailkomu -Subject $subject -Body $zprava -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $log
        }
}

There are 4 different paths in source .txt but there can be more paths. The count does not matter.
Checking for new files works perfectly.
The problem is, if there is a new file on e.g. the second path, it sends email immediately and does not wait for the other paths to be checked.
Example:
first path - no file - sends no email
second path - new file - sends email with log only for the first and the second path
third path - new file - sends email with log only for the first, second and the third path
fourth path - no file - sends no email

Is there a way how to make it works that it will check all paths, and if there are new files, it will send only one e-mail with log after checking all paths?

You just need a variable to keep track of whether any new files were found or not, and then move the Send-MailMessage call out of the loop - by waiting until after the loop is done you'll get at most 1 email, with the entire log, at once:
$source = Get-Content "C:\AAA\source.txt"
$logDate = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
$logtime = get-date -format HH:mm
$log = "C:\AAA\$logdate.log"

$mailkomu = "EEE@EEE.com"
$mailod = "GGG@GGG.com"
$subject = "New files in DDD"
$zprava = "Message"

# define variable to track whether new files have been found
$newFilesFound = $false

foreach ($path in $source) {
    # start by actually acting on whether the path describes an existing item
    $folderStatus = Test-Path $path
    if (-not $folderStatus) {
        # log failure to locate source folder, then continue on to the next source folder in the loop
        Write-Output "$logtime - $path - not found" | Out-File $log -Append 
        continue
    }

    Write-Output "$logtime - $path - ok" | Out-File $log -Append 

    # path exists, let's fetch all sub-items up front
    $childItems = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse)

    if ($childItems.Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "no files" | Out-File $log -Append
    }
    else { 
        Write-Output "new files" | Out-File $log -Append
        $data = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Select-Object DirectoryName, Name
        $data | Out-File $log -Append

        # set the indicator that files where found
        $newFilesFound = $true
    }
}

# only send email with log file if any new files were found
if ($newFilesFound) {
    Send-MailMessage -From $mailod -To $mailkomu -Subject $subject -Body $zprava -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $log
}


Thank you very much. It works perfectly. If I may ask, why is there $newFileFound = $false and then $true? I thougnt that the variable should not be the same. As a non-programer, it is a little bit confusing for me.

@Tomes: "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers." (see: https://stackoverflow.com/tour )

@Tomas: Did you notice, and try to understand the comment in the code # define variable to track whether new files have been found?  In words, The variable is keeping track if new files are found. So initially it will get the value $false, en it is being updated to $true when something is found.

Thank you for the explanation.  I read the comment but didn't quite understand it. It's clear to me now. Thank you.
